# Consume nested data in d3

Tags: javascript, json, csv, d3.js, charts

I am exploring d3. I am creating a bubble chart from very detailed and transactional csv data.

I have used d3.nest() and d3.rollup() remove unnecessary columns of the data and end up with final nested data structure. But I am not sure how to consume nested data in d3.

Here is the sample of my flat data ( Some columns are removed to display it better here on the post)

---

State,Date,Day,Month,Year,Dayweek,Crash Type,Number of Fatalities,Speed Limit

VIC,01-Jan-2015,1,January,2015,Thursday,Multiple vehicle,1,100

QLD,01-Jan-2015,1,January,2015,Thursday,Multiple vehicle,1,60

VIC,01-Jan-2015,1,January,2015,Thursday,Single vehicle,1,70

WA,01-Jan-2015,1,January,2015,Thursday,Single vehicle,1,110

TAS,01-Jan-2015,1,January,2015,Thursday,Single vehicle,1,40

SA,02-Jan-2015,2,January,2015,Friday,Multiple vehicle,1,60

QLD,03-Jan-2015,3,January,2015,Saturday,Multiple vehicle,1,100

NSW,04-Jan-2015,4,January,2015,Sunday,Single vehicle,1,100

WA,04-Jan-2015,4,January,2015,Sunday,Multiple vehicle,1,70

---

I converted above csv data to nested data using .nest() and .rollup() function. Converted data sample is as below

```js
Object {
  key: "VIC",  // group by state
  values: [
    {
      key: "January",   // group by month
      values: [
        {
          key: "40"    // group by speed limit
          values: {
            accidents: 1
            fatalities: 1
          }
        }, {..}, {..}
      ]
    }, {..}, {..}, {..}, {..}, {..} ...
  ]
```

My question is how can I consume data directly ?

1. Can I consume directly ?
2. Do I have to flatten this nested data to consume in d3 ?

If possible please provide some example ...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it. I could not answer anywhere. People have posted half answers but no one has put a solution that show you a way to flatten nested data.

**Q-1. Can I consume directly nested data?**

**A-1.** Yes it can be consumed nested data by d3. You have to add a `<svg:g></svg:g>` element for each level and that will hold the `__d__` value for the next level. And at any level, if you want to access the parent node data `var parentData = d3.select(this.parentNode).datum();`

**Q-2. Do I have to flatten this data to consume in d3? And how to flatten nested data to consume?**

**A-2.** This is much better approach, as it is one off operation, and all data available at each elements entered on SVG. Use `.map()` function to iterate though each level and flatten it.

**Exmaple**

```js
var flatdata = [];

data.map(function (d) {
  d.values.map(function (s) {
   var tdata = s.values.map(function (t) {
    return {
     state: d.key,
     month: s.key,
     speed: t.key,
     accidents: t.values.accidents,
     fatalities: t.values.fatalities
    }
   })
   flatdata = flatdata.concat(tdata);
  })
 });
```

I dont know that is the best solution but it is working perfectly fine.

Hope this will be helpful.